# Any gottcha's on using TTimer to monitor file dates and update screen?

Tags: delphi

I want to detect when a file date changes and update a DevX TdxMemData which is used as a Tdatasource which then would be seen in a TDBGrid that uses it.

I've found some code that uses ReadDirectoryChangesW, but seems rather complex for my simple needs.

I'm considering using a TTimer and firing it off every five seconds.  (That's fine enough accuracy for me.)

Are there any caveats in doing this?  I've read that Threads have all sorts of restrictions on VCL access, etc. Does the same thing apply to TTimer events?

Is there anything I need to watch out for when calling FileAge and updating a DevEx TdxMemData object while in a Timer event? Will those updates be seen by my main app?

Is there a way to detect the "state" of my program when a Timer event gets control so I can avoid problems?

Or am I opening an enormous can of worms in thinking about using a TTimer for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Demos directory there's "ShellChangeNotifier" component, which will fire events when files get modified, added or deleted inside directory. However it has only one OnChange event, so you don't know what really happened.

There's some discussion and solution about the issue in [about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/l/aa030403a.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer to the Embarcadero-provided component!

Comment: Harriv: I seem to be having trouble installing the demo component into D2010.

It's in C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls

I'm not familiar with installing components.  Thre's dproj in C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls, but I can't figure out how to install it in the IDE.

Thanks!!

Comment: I hope this helps: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Installing_Component_Packages

Comment: Thanks, Harriv. That did help. I loaded and compiled the dpk in the IDE.  However, trying to load the package, I get the message 


Package C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls\vclshlctrls140.bpl can't be installed because it is not a design time package.

Any further suggestions? (My apologies for dragging you in to this ditch.)

Comment: I've only Delphi 2009, but I installed to dclshctrl -package which is design time package and after that I got the TShellChangeNotifier in my component palette.

Answer (score 8):

TTimer events are called within the main application thread, so there's no problems with accessing VCL objects from them.  It's called when your application is idle, so it won't take place while your in an OnClick handler or anything similar unless you manually call Application.ProcessMessages.

I'd suggest using ReadDirectoryChangesW though.  If you use a timer you will continue polling even if the application is idle and the file isn't changing.  It will keep your CPU from going idle and keep could keep the hard drive from spinning down, which can have negative effects for power saving and battery usage.

Answer (score 4):

Windows lets you monitor file changes. As a jump start see http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/l/aa030403a.htm. There are several ready made components available, too. Google for "delphi monitor file change" or something similar

Answer (score 1):

You can check my: [DirectoryWatch](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/directory-watch/)

It is a wrapper around "ReadDirectoryChangesW" functions. It is more specific about changes than "ShellChangeNotifier".